# Mac: What is the ~/.TI-trace file for?

Tags: macos, mac, hidden-file

So I have this .TI-trace file in my home dir. Google search attempts have been uninformative.

Can someone tell me:

Why do I have it?
Can I not have it?
What's it for, what does it affect?

Comment: Could TI be Texas Instruments? Are you an electronics engineer or dabble in electronics? Do you use any TI software or equipment? What length is the file? If you run `file ~/.TI-trace`, what file type does it say it is?

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, it could be just about anything; prefs, license file, local storage, cache… sometimes badly-coded apps will throw prefs in there because they can't find the prefs folder. You might get some clues if you open it, in TextEdit or BBEdit etc.

If you throw it out & it was important, you might find you've lost a license to an app, or it might simply be re-created next time you launch it. Unless you're constantly looking in there, you may never even spot it happening. Alternatively, it could be from something you've long discarded, so it will never return.

I know what some of these are, not a clue about others…

[image]